# LASSO analysis (glmnet package). Can I loop the analysis and the results extraction?

Tags: r, glmnet

I'm using the package glmnet, I need to run several LASSO analysis for the calibration of a large number of variables (%reflectance for each wavelength throughout the spectrum) against one dependent variable. I have a couple of doubts on the procedure and on the results I wish to solve. I show my provisional code below:

1. First I split my data in training (70% of n) and testing sets.

   ```
   smp_size <- floor(0.70 * nrow(mydata))
   set.seed(123)
   train_ind <- sample(seq_len(nrow(mydata)), size = smp_size)
   train <- mydata[train_ind, ]
   test <- mydata[-train_ind, ]
   ```
2. Then I separate the target trait (y) and the independent variables (x) for each set as follows:

   ```
   vars.train <- train[3:2153]
   vars.test <- test[3:2153]

   x.train <- data.matrix(vars.train)
   x.test <- data.matrix(vars.test)
   y.train <- train$X1
   y.test <- test$X1
   ```
3. Afterwords, I run a cross-validated LASSO model for the training set and extract and writte the non-zero coefficients for lambdamin. This is because one of my concerns here is to note which variables (wavebands of the reflectance spectrum) are selected by the model.

   ```
   install.packages("glmnet")
   library(glmnet)
   cv.lasso.1 <- cv.glmnet(y=y.train, x= x.train, family="gaussian", nfolds = 
   5, standardize=TRUE, alpha=1)

   coef(cv.lasso.1,s=cv.lasso.1$lambda.min) # Using lambda min.
   (cv.lasso.1)

   install.packages("broom")
   library(broom)
   c <- tidy(coef(cv.lasso.1, s="lambda.min"))
   write.csv(c, file = "results")
   ```
4. Finally, I use the function “predict” and apply the object “cv.lasso1” (the model obtained previously) to the variables of the testing set (x.2) in order to get the prediction of the variable and I run the correlation between the predicted and the actual values of Y for the testing set.

   ```
   predict.1.2 <- predict(cv.lasso.1, newx=x.2, type = "response", s = 
   "lambda.min")
   cor.test(x=c(predict.1.2), y=c(y.2))
   ```

This is a simplified code and had no problem so far, the point is that I would like to make a loop (of one hundred repetitions) of the whole code and get the non-zero coefficients of the cross-validated model as well as the correlation coefficient of the predicted vs actual values (for the testing set) for each repetition. I've tried but couldn't get any clear results. Can someone give me some hint? 
thanks!

Comment: So, you are looking to bootstrap 100 samples of training variables and fits, and take the average of 100 predictions outcomes? Or are you looking to do this 100 times and use the best one? If it is the later, you will be increasing the odds of over fitting, if it is the first, you will be increasing the odds of overfitting...so what is the purpose of doing this?

Comment: Thanks for your repply @sconfluentus, The idea is to repeat 100 times the split of data (into training and testing sets) and the next steps (fitting of the model, extraction of coefficients and finally get the precision of the prediction with the R2 between predicted vs actual values). First, I want to know which variables are almost always selected by the model according to the non-zero coefficients (e.g. 80% of times). Second I want to average the R2 of all models. I'm novice in this analysis so I would appreciate any correction.

Answer (score 1):

In general, running repeated analyses of the same type over and over on the same data can be tricky. And in your case, may not be necessary the way in which you have outlined it.

If you are trying to find the variables most predictive, you can use PCA, Principal Component Analysis to select variables with the most variation within the a variable AND between variables, but it does not consider your outcome at all, so if you have poor model design it will pick the least correlated data in your repository but it may not be predictive. So you should be very aware of all variables in the set. This would be a way of reducing the dimensionality in your data for a linear  or logistic regression of some sort.

[You can read about it here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/FactoMineR/versions/1.39/topics/PCA)

`yourPCA <- prcomp(yourData,
                 center = TRUE,
                 scale. = TRUE)`

Scaling and centering are essential to making these models work right, by removing the distance between your various variables setting means to 0 and standard deviations to 1. Unless you know what you are doing, I would leave those as they are. And if you have skewed or kurtotic data, you might need to address this prior to PCA. Run this ONLY on your predictors...keep your target/outcome variable out of the data set.

If you have a classification problem you are looking to resolve with much data, try an LDA, Linear Discriminant Analysis which looks to reduce variables by optimizing the variance of each predictor with respect to the OUTCOME variable...it specifically considers your outcome.

`require(MASS)
 yourLDA =r <- lda(formula = outcome ~ ., 
         data = yourdata)`

You can also set the prior probabilities in LDA if you know what a global probability for each class is, or you can leave it out, and R/ lda will assign the probabilities of the actual classes from a training set. You can read about that here:

[LDA from MASS package](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/MASS/versions/7.3-47/topics/lda)

So this gets you headed in the right direction for reducing the complexity of data via feature selection in a computationally solid method. In looking to build the most robust model via repeated model building, this is known as crossvalidation. There is a `cv.glm` method in `boot` package which can help you get this taken care of in a safe way.

You can use the following as a rough guide:

`require(boot)
 yourCVGLM<- cv.glmnet(y = outcomeVariable, x = allPredictorVariables, family="gaussian", K=100)` . 
Here `K=100` specifies that you are creating 100 randomly sampled models from your current data OBSERVATIONS not variables.

So the process is two fold, reduce variables using one of the two methods above, then use cross validation to build a single model from repeated trials without cumbersome loops!

[Read about `cv.glm` here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/boot/boot.pdf)

Try starting on page 41, but look over the whole thing. The repeated sampling you are after is called booting and it is powerful and available in many different model types.

Not as much code and you might hope for, but pointing you in a decent direction.